# How to read CSV file data using GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am doing a project where i need to read data from excel and display it using flex table in Google Web toolkit....
if i try doing it as it is done in java then it gives following error at this line
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/test.xls"));

Line 43: No source code is available for type java.io.FileInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?

I am new at this...So please suggest me some method..I would really appreciate examples..

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read a file from a disk in GWT. You can ask a user to upload a file to your server, and there you can process it and return results to the client.

Or, if you already have the file, you don't need GWT at all. Read it in your server code, then give data to the client.

Comment: n could u link any example for hot to give data from server to client?

Comment: You should probably start with a tutorial on GWT RPC: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html